# How to select an app to automatic upload with xcrun?

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, xcrun

My company have more than 60 apps on the apple store (all the same base), so when we have an update, it takes a lot of times to upload all of them
So i'm trying to find a way to automate the maximum

I found something interesting for uploading an app with xcrun:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos Validation -online -upload -verbose "path to ipa"
```

So it validates and try to upload
But the issue is that if I have more than one app with the status "waiting for upload", it just picks the first one, I wanted to know if there is a way to specify the bundle id or the app id to select the one I want to upload ?

I found an idea of solution on internet, doing a script to change the status of only one app on the itunesconnect to 'waiting for upload', but I think it's kinda not safe, because if there is only one fail, it will be a pretty mess.

So if somebody has a solution by command line, thanks you to share !

Comment: Sorry I can't help you, but I had a question about your xcrun command. I'm not seeing -online and -upload as options for xcrun when I look at the man page for xcrun. Have these been deprecated?

Comment: i dont think it's deprecated, but i dont see either in the man so i dont know where you can get more info on these options...

Comment: already answered the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22987614/1971301

Answer (score 1):

Use application loader tool: 
altool --upload-app -f file -u username [-p password] [--output-format xml]

https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdATD1E53-D1E1A1303-D1E53A1126

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in my company. I solved it using `Validation -online "Pakcage with nonsence bundle"`, but it stops working from Xcode 5. They change the output of Validation binary.

So I managed to get it working with Xcode 5 by using:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos Validation -online -upload -verbose test.ipa | grep ExistingBundleIdentifier | head -n 1 | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
```

But this is so slow, because it need to actually try to upload the ipa.

Finally I ended up with script, that uses above example running in background, writing to log and checking, if there is Bundle in log, then I kill background process and continue as on Xcode 4.

You can also use Validation binary and some libs from Xcode 4.6.3, it also works, I tested it. But I don't want to use it. `xcrun -sdk iphoneos Validation -online test.ipa` gives you bundle without uploading.